# how to set umask for directory and exit places

Tags: bash, umask

I am writing a script which is creating directories to be used using the following command `mktemp -d`

I've to add a umask to the directories being created in the above way. And I've to add it to the exit conditions of the code.

Below is the sample code:

```
DIR1=$(mktemp -d)

wget_output=$(wget -q -P "$DIR1" "$CERT1")
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Certificates NOT Found OR Saving the certificates in directory failed."
        exit
    fi
```

How to do it?

Comment: Unclear. Doesn't mktemp obey umask? Or are you wanting to set a specific umask for it? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to set a specific value not the system default.

Comment: And it is not good enough to chmod it after the fact? Yes, that leaves a small window of vulnerability, but the danger from failing to set it back is worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In the begining of the file record original umask

`umask=$(umask)`

then set the value before the directory creation.

```
umask 077
DIR1=$(mktemp -d)

wget_output=$(wget -q -P "$DIR1" "$CERT1")
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Certificates NOT Found OR Saving the certificates in directory failed."
        exit
    fi
```

then in the end restore umask using

`umask ${umask}`

So, the updated code becomes:

```
umask=$(umask) #record umask
.
.
.
umask 077 # set umask value
DIR1=$(mktemp -d)

wget_output=$(wget -q -P "$DIR1" "$CERT1")
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Certificates NOT Found OR Saving the certificates in directory failed."
        exit
    fi

umask ${umask} # restore umask
```

Answer (score 1):

A better answer may be to shell, as the umask is held at the shell level.

```
$SHELL -c "umask $mask; mktemp -d"
```

This ensures that however the current script is exited it does not modify the current umask.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
umask 0700
DIR1="$(mktemp -d)"
```

Set the permission of DIR1 to 0700 (drwx------)

Comment: The umask here is incorrect. If I run your commands, I get the directory set to `d---------`. The umask should be something like `0077` for the permissions to end up like `drwx------`.